# Angular Typescript - Multi filter with check boxes

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, eventemitter

I'm working on a Stackblitz and have unfortunately hit a wall and are now just going round in circles!

I'm looking to filter an array based on multiple check boxes values that need to be included in a specific object in order for it to be left in the DOM.

Here is the Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ycebgh

This is my array json:

```
cards = [
    {
      name: "Daniel",
      profile: [
        {
          type: "Gender",
          name: "Male"
        },
        {
          type: "Fashion",
          name: "Footwear"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      profile: [
        {
          type: "Gender",
          name: "Male"
        },
        {
          type: "Family",
          name: "Children"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Sarah",
      profile: [
        {
          type: "Gender",
          name: "Female"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Janice",
      profile: [
        {
          type: "Gender",
          name: "Female"
        },
        {
          type: "Family",
          name: "Children"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I'm currently emitting the checkbox click event into the parent and i need the parent to then filter the objects depending on the checkbox values selected.

I've managed to do it with one at time but having multiple is proving to be a struggle.

Something like:

```
onFilter(options) {
    console.log(options);
    this.cards.filter(x => x.profile == options.value );
  }
```

Any insight into what I need to do to accomplish this would be great.

Comment: check : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njtabf

Comment: I have had to do something similar like this before. What I can suggest is emitting a value from the checkbox if it is checked. Then push that value to an array containing all your filtered values that you want to filter. Then you loop through those filtered values and see which ones are found in your data. Then if you find those items you push the data to an array containing only filtered items. You then display that array. If you uncheck a checkbox you then remove that value emitted from your filtered values array and your data will change accordingly.

Comment: @Florian thanks very much. The filtering is working correctly but the only issue this has caused is the sorting using the button (A-Z) is now not working. Any idea of how I could get round this?

Comment: @DanielBailey Do you have a code example of achieving this?

Comment: @DBoi i updated the stackblitz. What Daniel Bailey describe is what I did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had some troubles with the way you manage your data.

See this [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njtabf?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffilter.component.ts)

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much for helping out. Much appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate that you've answered my initial question but can you point me in the right direction to ensure that when the sorting button(A-Z) is clicked, the array will remain in alphabetical order when filtered? whats the simpliest way to achieve this?

Comment: You can set a boolean to know if clicked button is clicked. Evertyime you check a box, you order the array with your sortering method if the button is clicked

Comment: Like how you've achieved that - was different to my solution. i'm now implementing multiple sorting also such as sorting Z-A as well as A-Z. If you have time id love to see how you achieve this. Thanks a bunch! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8y8sq

Comment: @DBoi your new stackblitz is working i think, isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah you really helped me out - thank man. i was just wondering if there was a  cleaner way to achieve what i'm doing - always like to learn from different techniques.

Comment: @DBoi I'll try to take a moment on monday to rewrite the code "in my way". I'll drop a comment here when done

Comment: @DBoi : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkjfyq  I updated the stackblitz with my approach

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that. Has taught me about enums and really like the switch case you've implemented. Also the takeWhile operator - hadn't seen that before! thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok what you need is a change detection. In this case you can use ngModelChange. It will look like:

`(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)`"

And in the component:

```
onChange() {
    this.filter.emit(this.options);
  }
```

What this will do in ouput the change to your parent component. There you can read the array and do whatever you want to do with the data. From here on I think you can manage it yourself.

Comment: Hi Swoox, thanks for helping out. It was mainly the filtering side of things that i couldn't figure out. If possible I want to use the filter() method but get it to work with multiple values. Any idea on how I can achiveve this using filter() and comparing the checkbox values to the card.profile.name values?